# Can't run AVD (Ubuntu 18.04)

Tags: libraries, error-handling, android-sdk, android-emulator

I can't run AVD using command: `Sdk/tools/android avd`
But AVD works if launched through Android studio thought.

I tried these commands, but nothing changed:

```
cd Android/Sdk/emulator/lib64/libstdc++
mv libstdc++.so.6 libstdc++.so.6.bak
ln -s /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6
```

The error message:

```
Starting emulator for AVD 'Android_2.3.3API-10_2.7inch'
libGL error: unable to load driver: i965_dri.so
libGL error: driver pointer missing
libGL error: failed to load driver: i965
libGL error: unable to load driver: i965_dri.so
libGL error: driver pointer missing
libGL error: failed to load driver: i965
libGL error: unable to load driver: swrast_dri.so
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
X Error of failed request:  GLXBadContext
  Major opcode of failed request:  155 (GLX)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  6 (X_GLXIsDirect)
  Serial number of failed request:  60
  Current serial number in output stream:  59
libGL error: unable to load driver: i965_dri.so
libGL error: driver pointer missing
libGL error: failed to load driver: i965
libGL error: unable to load driver: i965_dri.so
libGL error: driver pointer missing
libGL error: failed to load driver: i965
libGL error: unable to load driver: swrast_dri.so
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
X Error of failed request:  GLXBadContext
  Major opcode of failed request:  155 (GLX)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  6 (X_GLXIsDirect)
  Serial number of failed request:  60
  Current serial number in output stream:  59
libGL error: unable to load driver: i965_dri.so
libGL error: driver pointer missing
libGL error: failed to load driver: i965
libGL error: unable to load driver: i965_dri.so
libGL error: driver pointer missing
emulator: WARNING: Classic qemu does not support SMP. The hw.cpu.ncore option from your config file is ignored.
libGL error: failed to load driver: i965
libGL error: unable to load driver: swrast_dri.so
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
X Error of failed request:  BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)
  Major opcode of failed request:  155 (GLX)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  24 (X_GLXCreateNewContext)
  Value in failed request:  0x0
  Serial number of failed request:  42
  Current serial number in output stream:  43
QObject::~QObject: Timers cannot be stopped from another thread
```

Answer (score 2):

I've just found the solution for my similar issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46988020/im-use-ubuntu-17-4-when-i-try-to-install-android-studio-and-run-my-virtual-devi):

> These are the exact steps you need to follow to solve the emulator
>   issue:
>
> 1. Change directory:
>
>    ```
>    $ cd ~/Android/Sdk/emulator/lib64/libstdc++
>    ```
> 2. Create symbolic link to library:
>
>    ```
>    $ mv libstdc++.so.6 libstdc++.so.6.bak
>    ```
> 3. on the same directory:
>
>    ```
>    $ ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
>    ```

That should fix it! As soon as it was applied I've got the virtual device running.

Comment: Not for me. I still see libGL errors.

Comment: This solved it for me